# Calculate road distance between two longitudes and latitudes

Tags: php, android, google-maps

I am trying to develop an android app. I have listed some places with their longitude/latitude and other descriptions in my backend(php MySQL). I am trying to grab users current location and show him the road distance to those listed places with their descriptions. But I am having difficulty finding road distances form current location to all other places. I guess one way to do this is by using [**Google Distance Matrix API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?csw=1)   But in this case there will be two API calls,

- 1st one from my device to my backend.
- 2nd one is from backend to Google Distance matrix API

and after that my backend will send response to my device. Is it a good Idea to call two API for this purpose. And is there any other way to do it easily. I am new to development so please pardon me if I am wrong.

Thank You.

Comment: Unless you have gps coordinates of every road and the ability to trace the best path through those roads to get your distance, then you are stuck with having to make the two api calls. Unless there was some way to instead make the call to google directly from your app.

Comment: i don't know that api much, but can't you call it from the device directly?

Comment: Even if I call the google API directly,I have to get the list of places and their details from my server first. So again 2 API calls for a single purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
public float distance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 6371; // kilometers
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLng / 2)
            * Math.sin(dLng / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

    return dist * 1000;
}
```

**Now Call in your code**

```
float distanceInMeters= distance(oldLatitude, oldLongitude,newLatitude, newLongitude);
```

Comment: Is this by road distance or normal distance between  two longitudes and latitudes?

Comment: Sorry. this is the latitude. but it works for routes as well.

To do this, simply call this function using the values ​​of the route of return

Comment: Thanks. but I don't know what is "route of return". can you please explain.